# How can I make attach this file to this code in appscript to be then emailed out

Tags: google-apps-script

Below code comes up with the error:

Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property getFileById on object DriveApp.

myFunction

@ Send Email Script for Sheets.gs:12

```
function myFunction() {
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let address = sheet.getRange("B1").getValue();
  let subject = sheet.getRange("B2").getValue();
  let body = sheet.getRange("B3").getValue();
  MailApp.sendEmail(address, subject, body);

    // File ID for the attachment (replace 'YOUR_FILE_ID' with the actual File ID)
  var file = "1J1MuYLLPYkviZ4M5Li8ZCLtiqJHQGJk_MzPMz1uVE6c/edit";

  // Get the file by ID
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(file);

  // Send email with attachment
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: recipientList,
    subject: subject,
    body: body,
    attachments: [file.getAs(MimeType.PDF)] // Change MimeType.PDF to the desired file type
  });
}


I'm hoping that the file listed can be added as an attachment to be then emailed using this script
```

Comment: Your code is not  a [mcve] because it has undefined variables and you have declared file twice

Comment: What is the file type

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
function myFunk01() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0")
  const [address, subject, body] = sh.getRange("B1:B3").getValues().flat();
  //MailApp.sendEmail(address, subject, body)
  var file = gobj.globals.msnwdocsid;
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(file);
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: address,
    subject: subject,
    body: body,
    attachments: [file.getAs(MimeType.PDF)] 
  });
}
```